# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,2) (1,5)

Tags: python, numpy, broadcasting

I want multiply this two np.array, I believe it should return a (5,2) np.array, but it raise an error.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.arange(10)
b = b.reshape((5,2))
print(a.shape, b.shape)
print(b * a)
```

Comment: I noticed that if I reshape b to (2,5), it won't be an error, why this happen???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to multiply a and b element-wise on each column, you need to add

`a = a.reshape((5,1))`

Comment: I know I can do this, but I don't understand why this cannot be done, since if we set a = np.array([1,2]), it won't raise an error.